# BottomNavigationView keeps checking last menuitem (when it starts up) but displays first menuitem

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

When the app first starts up, it checks the last menuitem as if it was clicked. It displays the first menuitem content. In Android Studio, no errors, warnings, or logs are displayed that hint at anything going wrong.

Once the app is running, if I click on any of the other menuitems, it works normal. I can click on each of the menuitems and the correct fragment populates accordingly.

Here is `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM = "arg_selected_item";

    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNav;
    private int mSelectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                selectFragment(item);
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem selectedItem;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedItem = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM, 0);
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(mSelectedItem);
        } else {
            selectedItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        }
        selectFragment(selectedItem);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM, mSelectedItem);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    /* This is never called on start up */
    public void onBackPressed() {
        MenuItem homeItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(0);
        if (mSelectedItem != homeItem.getItemId()) {
            // select home item
            selectFragment(homeItem);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment frag = null;

        // init corresponding fragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_home:
                frag = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_archives:
                frag = ArchivesFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_inspirational:
                frag = InspirationalFragment.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                frag = SearchFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        }

        // update selected item
        mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

        // unchecked the other items.
        //THIS LINE HERE
        for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
            menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == mSelectedItem);
        }

        updateToolbarText(item.getTitle());

        if (frag != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container, frag, frag.getTag());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    private void updateToolbarText(CharSequence text) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(text);
        }
    }
```

Here is `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ourdailystrength.mobile.android.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f1f1f1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `bottom_nav_items.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_48dp"
        android:checked="true" <!-- Doesn't matter if this line is included or not -->
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_archives"
        android:title="@string/menu_archives"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_archive_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_inspirational"
        android:title="@string/menu_inspirational"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Here is a screenshot of when it first boots up:

[image]

Why is the last menuitem being checked and not the first menuitem?

**EDIT**:
So, from answers given below, I made this change and it works:

```
private void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment frag = null;

    // update selected item
    mSelectedItem = item.getItemId();

    // unchecked the other items.
    for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
        menuItem.setChecked(false);
    }

    // init corresponding fragment
    switch (mSelectedItem) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            frag = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_home).setChecked(true);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_archives:
            frag = ArchivesFragment.newInstance();
            mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_archives).setChecked(true);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_inspirational:
            frag = InspirationalFragment.newInstance();
            mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_inspirational).setChecked(true);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_search:
            frag = SearchFragment.newInstance();
            mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_search).setChecked(true);
            break;
    }

    updateToolbarText(item.getTitle());

    if (frag != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, frag, frag.getTag());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Why would the `THIS LINE HERE` in the above code cause it to do this weird error?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you to resolve your issue. 
Call this method whenever you change the `Fragment`. Pass `checkedcolor` and `unchecked color` according to your needs.

```
 private void changeMenuItemCheckedStateColor(int checkedColor, int uncheckedColor) {
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
        };
        int[] colors = new int[]{
                uncheckedColor,
                checkedColor
        };
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(colorStateList);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 Solutions

1) Use **Group**

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
   <item .../>
   <item .../>
   <item .../>
</group>
```

2) Do it by programmatically

```
Menu bottomMenu;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationMenu = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
bottomMenu = navigation.getMenu();
bottomMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_home).setChecked(true);
```

Hope it will help , If you have any queries please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code:

```
// unchecked the other items.
        for (int i = 0; i < mBottomNav.getMenu().size(); i++) {
            MenuItem menuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem(i);
            menuItem.setChecked(menuItem.getItemId() == mSelectedItem);
        }
```

and give tint color in BottomNavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />
```